# Pros and cons of caching uniforms

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, lwjgl3

I am using LWJGL, and I have a `ShaderProgram` class that abstracts a GPU shader. I have a `bindUniform(int location, Object value)` method that binds a uniform to the shader (by calling appropriate subroutines based on the type of `value`, like `glUniformMatrix4fv`).

I predict that I will be facing many scenarios where the **value** of a currently bound uniform will be the same for the input of `bindUniform` in subsequent calls.

I consider implementing a caching logic that, for every call to `bindUniform()` will try to look up if the value is cached (by performing by value comparisons), and only if it isn't, it will call the underlying opengl `glUniform_()`, then save the value to the cache.

I wonder:

1. is this a minor micro optimization?
2. is the an optimization at all, considering some comparisons between matrices will be 16 `==` operations?

Comment: This sounds like a question you could answer conclusively for your use case by profiling. Otherwise, you'll get answers for someone else's use case, which might entail a different workload or target hardware than yours.